# Highlighting custom renderer Column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable that uses JTextArea as a custom renderer for one Column. When I select a row all the elements in that row are highlighted except for the column with the custom cell Renderer.

How can I get that column to highlight as well?

I use this code to populate and set my table

```
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
         jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));
         jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new wrap());
         updateRowHeights(3, 300);

                TableColumn c1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                TableColumn c2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                TableColumn c3 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
                TableColumn c4 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
                TableColumn c5 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
                TableColumn c6 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
                TableColumn c7 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6);
                TableColumn c8 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7);

                c1.setPreferredWidth(60);
                c2.setPreferredWidth(120);
                c3.setPreferredWidth(90);
                c4.setPreferredWidth(400);
                c5.setPreferredWidth(150);
                c6.setPreferredWidth(90);
                c7.setPreferredWidth(80);
                c8.setPreferredWidth(80);
```

This is Wrap class

```
class wrap extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
        wrap() {
            super();
            setLineWrap(true);
            setEditable(false);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 5, 10));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object value, boolean bln, boolean bln1, int i, int i1) {
            setText((String) value);
            setFont(jTable1.getFont());
            setBackground(jTable1.getBackground());
            setForeground(jTable1.getForeground());            
            return this;
        }

    }
```

I know it might be asking a lot but any possible explanation with a code sample would be highly appreciated since I am still a noob.

Here is an image sample of what is happening right now. Sorry I had to smudge out some of the data.[image]

Comment: The `boolean bln` corresponds to the isSelected flag. If it is `true`, `getTableCellRendererComponent` is supposed to return a "highlighted" `Component` .

Comment: Thank you so so much @Berger you are a lifesaver man.

Comment: You're welcome. Just in case, here is the javadoc of the method : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JTable-java.lang.Object-boolean-boolean-int-int-

Comment: Can I trouble you for one more thing @Berger, how do I update my database whenever someone changes a value in a cell. I have been looking online but have not been able to find a good answer that explains it well.

Comment: This is quite broad and would deserve a brand new question :)

Comment: Already started typing hope you will answer it as well.

Comment: Can not post for another 90 mins. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171792/discussion-between-mandeep-aulakh-and-berger).

Comment: @MandeepAulakh, `boolean bln, boolean bln1, int i, int i1` - use proper variable names. I have no ideas what those variable are. The API gives reasonable names. Use those. You also might want to start tagging your questions with the "Swing" tag to attract the attention of Swing programmers. We are not "JTable" only programmers.